# Python: Best way to get smartsheet Sheet by name

Tags: python, smartsheet-api

I'm looking to find a sheet via the Smartsheet api and all I have is the name of the sheet. I'm currently solving it like this

```
sheet_name = 'The sheet I have the name of'
sheets = ss_client.Sheets.list_sheets(include_all=True).data
sheet_id = next(sheet.id for sheet in sheets if sheet.name == sheet_name)

sheet_that_I_want = ss_client.Sheets.get_sheet(sheet_id)
```

There is a [get_sheet](https://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?python#get-sheet) method, but it's based of the sheet's id. I feel like there has to be a more direct way of doing this, but I'm not sure what it would be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sheet names don't have to be unique, so there isn't an endpoint for getting a sheet by name.

However, you could use the [search](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/?python#search-everything) endpoint to search for the sheet by name, and then sift through those results, which will potentially be smaller than iterating over all of your sheets.

```
sheet_name = "Demo"
search_results = ss_client.Search.search(sheet_name).results

sheet_id = next(result.object_id for result in search_results if result.object_type == 'sheet')
sheet_that_I_want = ss_client.Sheets.get_sheet(sheet_id)
print(sheet_that_I_want)
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that if I create a sheet and then search for it, it won't be found. It takes a few seconds to update the indexes. Using list_sheets seems to always include the one just created.

Answer (score 0):

There is a sheet_by_name call.

```
smartsheet_client = smartsheet.Smartsheet(token)

all_sheets = smartsheet.sheets.Sheets(smartsheet_client)
test_sheet = all_sheets.get_sheet_by_name("Demo")
print(testsheet.name)
```